# Attempting to use HTTP Url Request and Parse JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

An API that I'm trying to use gives has an HTTP Url Request that it gives developers so that they may call the API.

The problem with this URL is that it contains too many " % " signs, therefore I get this warning:

More " % " conversions than data arguments.

Here is the code where I create an instance of NSString with the URL:

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/%@?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY", searchText];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, there is UTF-8 code in your NSString. (those 0%3A20...)

And the correct way to handle this is...

1. Below is your url that before encode

   ```
   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/%@?results=0:20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name,brand_name&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY", searchText];
   ```
2. Encode the string afterwards

   ```
   NSLog(@"encodedString : %@", [urlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
   ```

Feel free to ask follow up question if you have any. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"your_url"]
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...
make suru that there should not be % sign in between or you must have argument for every format specifier..

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/%@?results=03A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name,brand_name&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY", searchText];